# update GitHUB forked project not the master

Tags: git, github

This is a noob question, but I forked a project and made few edits to it. So now I wish to do the following,

Step 1:

Update the forked project with my changes from Machine 1. is it possible to update forked project and keep the original (master) untouched?

Step 2:

pull the updated fork to machine 2.

Also when I forked the project, I forked it using the online portal and manually downloaded the tarball.
So can I update the forked project??

Both Machine 1 and machine 2 have there SSH keys in the GitHUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you forked the project, github created a copy of repository under your account. You should be able to pull it using

```
git clone git@github.com:[your user name]/[repository name].git
```

Then when you make your changes, you'd commit them and push the updates to github:

```
git push origin master
```

Once you did that, repeat cloning of the repository on your second machine which will then have the up-to-date version of the repository.

Comment: okay so when I manually forked, using the website, it is not considered cloning?

Comment: @Sam007 Forking creates a repository on Github, which you must then clone to your machine.

Comment: No, when you forked it via website, github created a new repository under your account.

Comment: ok so when I downloaded the tarball is not the same as cloning?

Comment: So now that I have the changes made in the folder which i manually downloaded how do I update that in the forked repo? will the same commands you gave, help?

Comment: One way to do it is 1) clone a repository to a new folder 2) copy the updated files into that folder 3) commit changes to repository (`git commit -a`) 4) push changes to github (`git push origin master`)

Comment: ok i ma bit confused about `git push origin master`

Does it update the original project or only the forked repo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11162/discussion-between-sam007-and-bluesrockaddict)

Comment: Just found one thing that makes life easier, instead of `commit -a` we can do `commit -a -m <reason for change>`. Makes life easier

Answer (score 3):

Your steps here would be to:

1. Fork the repo into your account. Then clone that down to your machine. (any changes made to your fork won't go to the original project)
2. Make changes and commit to your fork in your account
3. I would then make a pull request to the original repo

For your second machine, just reclone your project onto machine #2 and everything should be there.

Downloading the tarball isn't the same as cloning.

Checkout these instructions: http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Comment: ah @Steve i am new to git can u also provide the required commands

Comment: @Sam007 I added a link to the github instructions which are very good.